# gnuplot fill area under curve alternatively

Tags: gnuplot

I am having some difficulty generating a plot of a data set that is oscillating between negative and positive values (line a sin or cos). My goal is to fill the area under the curve with alternating colour: negative region with blue and positive with red. To be more precise I want to fill the area between the curve and the x axis. So far i managed to plot the curve with alternating colours (blue for negative, red for positive) using:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'red', 1 'blue' )
unset colorbox
plot 'data.set' u 1:2:( $2 < 0.0 ? 1 : 0 ) w lines lt 1 lw 4 palette
```

Unfortunately if I replace `w lines` with `filledcurves` I don't get an alternate fill. How can one accomplish this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you can try this:

```
plot '+' using 1:(0):(sin($1)) w filledc below, \
     '+' using 1:(0):(sin($1)) w filledc above
```

which is telling `gnuplot` to fill the area between two curves (`sin(x)` and `0`), using the above and below positions. There is another solution as well:

```
plot '+' using 1:(sin($1) > 0 ? sin($1):0) w filledcurves y1, \
     '+' using 1:(sin($1) < 0 ? sin($1):0) w filledcurves y2
```

and the result would be:

[image: output]

The important part refers to the `options` part of `filledcurves`. See more details [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node245.html) and [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/fillbetween.html).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!